# All file Extensions supported by Mozilla Firefox/ IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser

Can any please help me in finding all the file extensions that are natively displayed inside the firefox and IE browsers? For example, image extensions like .png, ..gif are natively displayed inside the browser.  Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

It's possibly not all of them but it's pretty darn comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you Rushyo, I appreciate the answer, I too have compiled a list of file types that can be opened in different browsers either natively or with help of plugins or are not at all compatible , will attach a link to it once complete. Again thank you.

Comment: <- Please mark answered if appropriate with the tick on the left :)